# How to configure ddclient to refresh every 30 days?

Tags: dynamic-dns

Can ddclient be configured in `/etc/ddclient.conf`, to send dynamic DNS updates periodically, in addition to when the IP address changes?

Why? Fremium provider dyndns requires an update be made every 30 days, else a free account expires.  I switched from AT&T where this was never a problem to a Sonic.net, a more reliable service provider.  Now my dynamic IP address is stable for months at a time.

Comment: To be clear: I'm on an ISP that has very stable DHCP, so my IP address may stay the same for 30 or more days.  If ddclient detects a change it updates dyndns, else it stays silent and my account expires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the ddclient README:

```
USING DDCLIENT WITH cron

If you have not configured ddclient to use daemon-mode, you'll need to
configure cron to force an update once a month so that the dns entry will
not become stale.

  ## configure cron to force an update twice a month
  cp sample-etc_cron.d_ddclient /etc/cron.d/ddclient
  vi /etc/cron.d/ddclient
```

Comment: Cron? I guess I missed the obvious, assuming ddclient had the function built in.